# Можете подсказать хорошую литературу/статьи на тему управления основными данными( Master Data Management)?

Tags: база-данных, книги

Подскажите литературу на тему управления основными данными( Master Data Management), если такое возможно, то на русском.
В русском сегменте я пытался найти какие-нибудь книжки, но что-то не нашел.
Касательно статеек на русском, то я их находил, но все они какие-то маленькие, хотелось что-нибудь по содержательнее.

Comment: Может проще английский освоить...http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4151487/ http://media.techtarget.com/searchDataManagement/downloads/MasterDataManagementSOA1.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот статьи, что удалось найти по этой теме (возможно Вам попадались не все из этого списка). С книгами же на русском сложнее, да.

- [Что такое Мастер-Данные и зачем они нужны](https://habrahabr.ru/company/navicon/blog/260927/)
- [Задачи управления мастер-данными](http://www.osp.ru/os/2007/05/4260254/)
- [Управление справочными данными: гибкий подход](http://www.iemag.ru/master-class/detail.php?ID=28880)
- [Семантическое управление справочными данными на предприятиях машиностроительного профиля](https://sk.ru/news/m/skmedia/1282/download.aspx)
- [Управление справочными данными: аналитический обзор рынка](http://semanticmdm.ru/images/file/article_ru/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%E2%80%89%E2%80%94%E2%80%89%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0.pdf)
- [Справочные данные и знания в управлении производством](http://machinery.ascon.ru/source/articles/andrichenko.pdf)

---

Список продуктов для УОД (MDM) от IMB, Oracle и SAP (подробнее смотреть здесь [Управление справочными данными: аналитический обзор рынка](http://semanticmdm.ru/images/file/article_ru/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%E2%80%89%E2%80%94%E2%80%89%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0.pdf)):

- IBM - InfoSphere Master Data Management Server
- Oracle - Customer Data Hub (CDH)
- Oracle - Siebel Universal Customer Master (UCM)
- Oracle - Product Information Management (PIM)
- Oracle - Hyperion Data Relationship Management (DRM)
- SAP - SAP NetWeaver Master Data Management (SAP MDM)